# How do I make a junit white list of tests to run

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I'm working on writing unit tests for a class that I'm developing.  Another developer is developing other tests for the same class for methods that he's developing.  So our tests find themselves in the same JUnit test class.

So what I wanted to do was to set up a test suite to run just my tests while I'm developing as a temporary measure.  I created a Category for my tests and have marked them as such.  I then created a class to be my test suite.  I told it to include tests that belong to this category.  When I run it, it still runs everything.  There are a lot of tests, so it would be tedious to mark all the tests I don't want ran with @Ignore.  Is there a way to say, run only the tests in a category but none else?

Comment: How do you run the test? If you use maven surefire plugin there is a way to exclude or include some test based on metacharacter (*).

Comment: You're both working on the same project, and you're each writing separate tests right? (good practice!) ... but you want to "only" run your tests - correct?

Comment: Why not have two test classes? Or work in a branch where only your work is changing source?

Comment: Why not run either a single test or all the tests? After all, all tests under source control must either run or be ignored...

Comment: your setup sounds good. maybe a wrong configuration: Could you add some code?

Comment: @Alepac - I'm running the tests through eclipse.

Comment: @pal - Yes.  We're writing separate tests.  We're working on separate parts of the same class and thus are testing different methods.  I simply don't want his results to be mixed with mine during development.  But ultimately they should be in the same test class.

Comment: @DaveNewton  I really don't want two class.  I suppose I could temporary create a separate class for my tests and then merge them in the end.

Comment: @Puce I have about 7 tests, the other developer has about 40 or 50 tests.  My tests are related and I just want to focus on them instead of hunting them within his tests.  I don't want to run one at a time because I would like to see all my tests pass at the same time without having to run it seven times.

Comment: @JasonThompson I don't see what the issue is with two classes, plus a class with 40+ methods in it is unmanageable anyway. IMO the tests should be broken out by functionality into more communicative classes.

Comment: You might want to include an SSCCE showing how you are setting up and running your category.

Comment: @DaveNewton It's not a "big" deal to have two classes, but considering the code, it doesn't make sense.  Many of the tests are things like:

testTSMethod()
testTSMethod_passingNullAsArg()
testTSMethod_someEdgeCase()
testTSMethod_verifySomethingTripsSomeException()
testJTsMethod()
testJTsMethod_verifyItWorksDuringNewMoonsOnLeapDays()
testJTsMethod_verifyItWorksUnderAlienInvasion()
etc...

So its not unmanageable like a monster class that does everything.  We're just thorough in what we test.  Unfortunately JUnit doesn't preserve test order so that sorting tests is easy.

Comment: Ugh...  Guess comments don't preserve formatting...  Sorry about the mess above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a wrapper test class which method calls the main test class (only your method), then run Junit tests on the wrapper class.

```
public class MainTestClass {
    @Test
    public void yourFirstTest() {
    ...
    }

    @Test
    public void yourSecondTest() {
    ...
    }

    @Test
    public void otherFirstTest() {
    ...
    }
}

public class WrapperTestClass {
    @Test
    public void yourFirstTest() {
       new MainTestClass().yourFirstTest();
    }

    @Test
    public void yourSecondTest() {
       new MainTestClass().yourSecondTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement your own 'org.junit.runner.RunWith' and then annotate your test class to use it as necessary.

```
    @RunWith(MyRunnerClass.class)
```

Note: The correct solution here is in the above comments regarding code branches etc.